# 3-DNF proves the algorithm is in P class

Tags: satisfiability, decision-problem

[To understand fully, please read link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/107183/will-this-algorithm-always-solve-a-constrained-sudoku-puzzle-in-quadratic-time)

After, reading the link we will take a look at how we recover our solutions to a constrained Sudoku Puzzle.

If we assume that a sudoku puzzle was generated with this procedure we can now create a "semi"-solver. I say "semi" because we need the $3 \times 3$ grid $M_{2,2}$ already solved for us. Let's assume we have this. As an example I will assume we are provided:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 9 & 6\\
1 & 2 & 4\\
3 & 7 & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we will flatten it into: $[5,9,6,1,2,4,3,7,8]$ and permute as follows:

```
[8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]-----list 1
[7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3]-----list 2
[3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4]-----list 3
[4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2]-----list 4
[2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1]-----list 5
[1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6]-----list 6
[6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9]-----list 7
[9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5]-----list 8
[5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]-----list 9
```

Now for each list, we will turn them into a $3 \times 3$ grid using the same mapping in step 2 above. For example list 1 would get mapped to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
8 & 5 & 9 \\
6 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 3 & 7 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now we position these in the game board the same way we did as step 3 above. For example our layout would be as follows:

```
**list1**  **list4**  **list7**

**list2**  **list5**  **list8**

**list3**  **list6**  **list9**
```

In the prior example this would give us the correct solution:

$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
8 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 2\\
6 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 9 & 4 & 3 & 7\\
4 & 3 & 7 & 6 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 5 & 9\\
7 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 1\\ 
9 & 6 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 4 & 3\\
2 & 4 & 3 & 9 & 6 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 5\\ 
3 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 6\\
5 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 8 & 1 & 2 & 4\\ 
1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & 9 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 8\\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then we have list 9 (our input) will always give you correct solution in quadratic time.

For further illustration, I intend to prove that the algorithm aforementioned is in P class in two ways.

Here, we'll take a look at **3-DNF**.

**(L1 ∧ L2 ∧ L3) | (L4 ∧ L5 ∧ L6) | (L7 ∧ L8 ∧ L9)**

Let **L1**=list1, **L2** = list2,...

```
**list1**  **list4**  **list7**

**list2**  **list5**  **list8**

**list3**  **list6**  **list9**
```

Therefore, the algorithm generates grids and recovers correct solutions easily.

Now, lets say I want to check the satsifiability of the algorithm's circular shifts. Here, I generate 3 more grids to show that there is a 3x3 positive *3-satisfying permutes*.

**l = [8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]**

```
[5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]-l1
[9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5]-l2
[6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9]-l3
[1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6]-l4
[2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1]-l5
[4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2]-l6
[3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4]-l7
[7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3]-l8
[8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]-l9
```

**x = [5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]**

```
[9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5]-x1
[6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9]-x2
[1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6]-x3
[2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1]-x4
[4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2]-x5
[3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4]-x6
[7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3]-x7
[8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]-x8
[5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]-x9
```

**y = [9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5]**

```
[6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9]-y1
[1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6]-y2
[2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1]-y3
[4, 3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2]-y4
[3, 7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4]-y5
[7, 8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3]-y6
[8, 5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7]-y7
[5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]-y8
[9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8, 5]-y9
```

Here, I demonstrate that the 3x3 shift meets satisfiability for 9! Sudoku grids generated by the algorithm. At the end of the question I prove that the expression is always meets satisfiability when given the correct inputs.

*(l1 ∨ x9 ∨ y8) ∧ (l2 ∨ x1 ∨ y9)*

**l1 = [5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]**

**x9 = [5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]**

**y8 = [5, 9, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 8]**

All the listed elements above have their defined variables within these expressions. All the expressions hold true.

> (1∨9∨8)∧(2∨1∨9)∧(3∨2∨1)∧(4∨3∨2)∧(5∨4∨3)∧(6∨5∨4)∧(7∨6∨5)∧(8∨7∨6)∧(9∨8∨7)∧(1∨9∨8)∧(2∨1∨9)

Here is a chart showing the 3-satsifiability of the algorithm. Proving that the 3x3 shift overlaps all 9! valid grids that the algorithm can generate

[image]

*Overall, are these proofs correct that constrained Sudoku is in P class?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As I already explained earlier](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/107347/755), any algorithm on a 9x9 input takes constant time.  Thus it is in P.  This is not very interesting or useful.

When people talk about Sudoku being NP-hard, they don't actually mean Sudoku, they are referring to a generalization on a grid of arbitrary size.  Your question doesn't prove that this generalized problem is in P.

General comment: It looks like you're immersed in details, but haven't got a solid grasp on the fundamentals/basics yet.  I encourage you to spend some more time learning about the definition of languages, decision problems, P, NP, NP-complete, NP-hard, and reductions before trying to take your Sudoku "project" any further.  As it stands some of your statements appear to reflect a misunderstanding of basic concepts, and so you're spending time on things that are a dead end or reflect some basic misconceptions.  (For instance, an algorithm can't be in P, and a proof can't be in; a problem can be.)  I hope you'll take this as aimed to help you learn, rather than an attempt to criticize you personally or tear you down.

Comment: Okay, I was just going to build upon a new questions after reading through reductibility and etc on Wikipedia. And, I'm building upon the same subject on every new question. I'll accept your answer while I formulate a new question as I'm getting more clarification step by step(both reading and asking)

Comment: @TravisWells, Cool!  I'd suggest finding a good textbook or an online course on algorithms or complexity theory.  Wikipedia isn't a great resource.  Don't expect it to be something you can learn in one sitting.  Have fun -- it's a beautiful subject!

Comment: I'm in the process of formulating a question about NM-3sat. Which is basically no mixed instances.    (eg. L1 or x9 or y8) and (l2 or x1 or y1)                                                                          
                                                                                                                              
 No negations unless all variables are negated. I was wondering if it would be possible to reduce DNF to NM-3sat showing that constrained puzzles can be just as hard to solve.